# QComboBox and QSpinBox in QTableWidget with appropriate alignment

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, spinner, qtablewidget

How to create a QTable widget which has 2 columnes, and in first column there is a QComboBox and in the second column there is a QSpinBox so that the combo box gets all the space of table and only a very small place leaves for QSpinBox (for 2-3 digits).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, use [`setCellWidget()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget) to set the `QComboBox` and `QSpinBox` as the widgets to be displayed in the appropriate cell.

Second, use `horizontalHeader()` to access the [`QHeaderView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html) for the `QTableView`, then set the [`ResizeMode`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum) accordingly.

```
QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget( this );
table->setColumnCount( 2 );
table->setRowCount( 1 );
table->setCellWidget ( 0, 0, new QComboBox( table ) );
table->setCellWidget ( 0, 1, new QSpinBox( table ) );
table->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode( 0, QHeaderView::Stretch );
table->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode( 1, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents );
```

Comment: QSpinBox is smaller then befor but it is still very big. I can write there about 11 digits, but I need only 2 or 3

Comment: Actually everything is OK indeed. It is big because its caption(the note in the table header) is big.