# QtableWidget: add QCombobox in insertRows()

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I've a QTableWidget and a QTableModel.

I want to create a column in which there are combobox instead of text.

I've found some answer, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172415/qcombobox-and-qspinbox-in-qtablewidget-with-appropriate-alignment) but they talk about fixed size tables.

I use instead `QAbstractTableModel::insertRows()` and `QAbstractTableModel::removeRows()` in order to change at Runtime the number of rows.

How can I add rows with the combobox at specified column in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way it's done in answer you find. (  `table->setCellWidget ( row, col, new QComboBox( table ) );`  ) 
The only problem is that you need to know which exact rows you've added with [insertRows()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#insertRows)

Comment: and where I must put this code? after endInsertRows()?

Comment: Exactly, `insertRows()` only adds empty rows, so you have to know which rows that are in order to populate them. [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#insertRows) you can find how `insertRows()` adds those empty rows