# Edit QTableView with combo box in column

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, tableview

I created my own `TableView` and implemented model for it, etc. Finally, I started to edit values : it went well with `flags` and `setData` functions reimplemented, but I can only edit string/int values. I need to add possibility to select from combo box there. I saw topics like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172415/qcombobox-and-qspinbox-in-qtablewidget-with-appropriate-alignment), but `QTableView` doesn't have a `setCellWidget` method.

Is there any possibility to implement it with `QTableView` or do I have to switch to 'TableWidget' and re-do my work (which would be problematic)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QTableView` has a method `setIndexWidget()` to display a widget in the particular cell. But in your case you should use a **delegate** derived from the `QItemDelegate` and reimplement the `createEditor()` method to create your combo-box.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Tomas's answer you will also need to reimplement the `setEditorData` and `setModelData` functions.

- `setEditorData` is used to get the data from the model and set the initial value of the editor.
- `setModelData` updates the data in the model according to the data entered in the editor.

Comment: The standard Qt example [spinboxdelegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-spinboxdelegate-example.html) has an example of a `QItemDelegate` subclass.