How to update a QTableView in the main window, with the contents of a QLineEdit box in a separate file
Simplified code:
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->lineEdit->text();

    // Needs code here to update the table in the mainwindow file. But i cannot access the mainwindows table object...
    
    close();
}


#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_actionadd_triggered()
{
    Dialog *dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog->show();
}


I have tried just 'including' the appropriate files. And I have tried to access the Table object from the Dialog file (where I commented), but had no joy.

Use signals and slots. create a signal in Dialog that is connected to a slot in MainWindow that transfers the data.

Thanks for the reply. Can I be cheeky and ask for some code? Only, I have been messing around with signals and slots all morning without any success. Yes, I am quite thick!

Do you really need a dialog box to popup and update an item in a QTableView? I am not sure that this is the best method. You may want this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475649/edit-qtableview-with-combo-box-in-column

Do any of these help: Qt method call from another class? || Accessing a class from another class Qt || Access a variable from another class?

I will take a look at those links, thankyou very much guys!

The fact that objects are defined in separate files is irrelevant: when your program runs, they will be stored in the memory of your 1 machine executing it and should be able to access one another: all you need is for 1 of your object to be "aware" of the other.
If what you want truly was to type text in a separate QDialog (i.e. not use a delegate nor an index widget, a simple signal/slot connection between the 2 will do.
On top of being simple, it is also more clean than coding it the Dialog class since objects will only need to access their children, as opposed to accessing their "cousins".
MainWindow knows about Dialog; in fact, this is where the pointer to your Dialog instance gets created. With that knowledge, what you need is:

In dialog.h, create a signal that takes a QString/QString reference as argument:

class Dialog {
Q_OBJECT
public:
// Your methods go here
public slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
signals:
    void text_added(const QString&);
};


In mainwindow.h, create the slot that the above signal will trigger. It needs to take a QString as parameter:

class MainWindow {
Q_OBJECT
public:
// Your methods go here
public slots:
    void on_actionadd_triggered();
    void on_dialog_text_added(const QString&);
};


In mainwindow.cpp, define the slots and connect the dialog signal to it:

void MainWindow::on_actionadd_triggered()
{
    Dialog *dialog = new Dialog(this);
    connect(dialog, &Dialog::text_added, this, &MainWindow::on_dialog_text_added);
    dialog->show();
}

void MainWindow::on_dialog_text_added(const QString& text)
{
   // Here goes the instruction, for instance:
   // QAbstractItemModel* model = ui->Table->model();
   // model ->setData(model ->index(...), text, Qt::EditRole);
}

